# finding two or more consecutive words starts with upper and replacing with their abbreviation (regex)

Tags: python, regex, words

i want to replace two or more consecutive words that starts with an upper character and replace them with their abbreviation, i managed to find the words with

```
def find(name):
        return re.findall('([A-Z][a-z]+(?=\s[A-Z])(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]+)+)', name)
```

but when i try to replace the words i just couldn't manage to do it

here what i got

```
import re


def main():
    name = raw_input(" Enter name: ")

    print find(name)


def find(name):
    return re.sub(r'([A-Z][a-z]+(?=\s[A-Z])(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]+)+)', replacement, name)


def replacement(match):
    return match.group[0].upper()

main()
```

for example

input: I went to the Annual General Meeting.
Output: I went to the AGM.

appreciate any help

Comment: hmm wont this be odd in the sentence:  'My name is Scott Jones' which would become 'My name is SJ'

Comment: yeah but i added couple of exclusions to the regex so that it wont take 'initials' if its preceded by a title eg: Mr or Ms etc

Comment: My example didn't have a title though.

Comment: Yeah in this case it wouldn't work, but since the input is provided by me I can make sure that every name has a title, that's how I solved it and I think it's pretty difficult to make it recognize names to avoid this problem...no?

Comment: you can use third party libraries to detect names or write a custom parser to detect them.

Comment: yeah i could but i think in my case it just doesn't worth it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify your `replacement` function as follows, your example should be in working order:

```
def replacement(match):
    return ''.join(y[0] for y in m.group(0).split())
```

Answer (score 1):

## Description

Here I'm using two separate expressions, the first one pulls all title cased words where the words with 2 or more words in a row. And the second expression pulls the first letter of each word... These are stitched together using logic to replace the values in your source string.

`(?:^|\s+)((?:\s*\b[A-Z]\w{1,}\b){2,})`

[image]

`\b([A-Z])`

[image]

## Example

```
$Regex = '(?:^|\s+)((?:\s*\b[A-Z]\w{1,}\b){2,})'
$String = 'I went to the Annual General Meeting with some guy named Scott Jones on Perl Compatible Regular Expressions. '

Write-Host start with 
write-host $String
Write-Host
Write-Host found
$Matches = @()
([regex]"$Regex").matches($String) | foreach {
    $FoundThis = $_.Groups[1].Value
    write-host "group one $($_.Groups[1].Index) = '$($FoundThis)'"

    [string]$Acronym = ""
    ([regex]"\b([A-Z])").matches($FoundThis) | foreach {
        $Acronym += $_.Groups[1].Value
        } # next match

    $String = $String -replace $FoundThis, $Acronym
    } # next match


Write-Host $String
```

Yields

```
start with
I went to the Annual General Meeting with some guy named Scott Jones on Perl Compatible Regular Expressions. 

found
group one 14 = 'Annual General Meeting'
group one 57 = 'Scott Jones'
group one 72 = 'Perl Compatible Regular Expressions'
I went to the AGM with some guy named SJ on PCRE.
```

## Disclaimer

- yes I know OP asked for a python example but I'm more familiar with powershell. The logic would be the same.
- As noted this will match proper names and if the first word of the sentence happens to be title cased followed by a title cased second word. So you'll need to do your own error checking

Comment: thanks for this thoroughly answer, i appreciate taking time of your day to help me.